# (ODR) OnDemandResource 'beginAccessingResources was called more than once or at the wrong time (3)

Tags: ios, swift, on-demand-resources

I am trying to introduce ODR in my application and facing the following crash.

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'beginAccessingResources was called more than once or at the wrong time (3)'`

This is what I have done so far.

1. Created two asset packs with Tags **Bell1** and **Bell2**.
2. Requesting for Bell1 tag on *appDidFinishLauching* after calling *conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler*.
3. Requesting for Bell2 on the **viewDidLoad** of the Home controller after the login is done.

(Just FYI: I am not calling **endAccessingResources** anywhere for the time being.)

If I remove the step 3 or request both resources in a single request then the app works fine. If I create two simultenous NSBundleResourceRequest then the app is crashing.

So far I have searched stackoverflow and read the documentation but couldn't find any help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the problem. I was calling `beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler` on a same **NSBundleResourceRequest** object multiple times.

So I solved it by creating a new *NSBundleResourceRequest* instance for each subsequent request.